# White screen after click on setting before loading the source in Exoplayer

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have implemented Exoplayer on my Live TV app. But when I click the setting icon (which will change the video quality from the source) before loading the source URL, the screen will white and after that automatically return to the home screen. But if I wait for full loading even if video buffering, setting icons work perfectly. For my question clarification, I added an image.
[image]

Here is the java code of settings button:

```
imgAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo;
            DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters parameters = trackSelector.getParameters();
            TrackSelectionDialog trackSelectionDialog =
                    TrackSelectionDialog.createForTrackSelector(
                            trackSelector,
                            /* onDismissListener= */ dismissedDialog -> {
                            });
            trackSelectionDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });
```

and the XML layout code:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_audio"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_white"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide code for both your button's logic and the xml layout in which you embedded the player view.

Comment: @Volnutt I added java and xml code...